# R does not assign colors to plot() function

Tags: r, colors, scatter-plot

So i wanted to revise my R knowledge with what I had seen in class last year, but I came across a problem. I wanted to generate a plot for a file about flowers, with colors in the plot specific for each flower (setosa, versicolor, virginica). This worked last year, but the exact same code now gives me an error:

```
> irisData <- read.table("irisData2.txt", header=TRUE)

> plot(x=irisData$Sepal.Length, y=irisData$Petal.Length, col=irisData$Species)

> Error in plot.xy(xy, type, ...) : invalid color name 'setosa'
```

This gave me a scatterplots with three colors, each for one species, but now it just doesn't work. How can I solve this?
Note: I use a new laptop now, and I updated R to the latest version (1.4.1106).
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably used to run this code on an R version <4.0 and now you’re running it on R 4.0.

R 4.0 changed the default handling of string columns in `read.table` (and other functions). As a consequence, the `Species` column of your data.frame is now of type `character`, where it used to be of type `factor`.

To make your code work again, change the column type:

```
irisData$Species = as.factor(irisData$Species)
```

---

To offer a more detailed explanation of the error message, `plot`’s `col` argument accepts either a vector of colours, or a vector of *numbers* (or factors, which are internally integers). If the argument is a vector of numbers, then these numbers are used to index into the currently set `palette()`. However, if the argument is a character string vector (as it is in your code when running on R 4.0), then these are interpreted as colour names/values instead of indices in the current palette. This fails, since the “iris” species aren’t valid colour names.

Comment: another way to go about this is to read the data frame with the strings as factors automatically (the previous default behaviour). All you need to do is run 
`irisData <- read.table("irisData2.txt", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = T)`